# Convert String to date and return as JSON with number

Tags: php, json, date

I would like to get below result as Json from PHP

```
[
[Date.UTC(2013,5,2),76.95],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,3),76.48],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,4),76.45],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,5),764.38],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,6),5.49],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,7),635.62],
[Date.UTC(2013,6,1),76.54],
[Date.UTC(2013,6,2),77.05],
[Date.UTC(2013,6,3),76.87]
]
```

I'm getting below result as of now by below code , tried many things but couldn't able to make it work. Need experts helps...

```
 while($selected = $statement->fetch()){
    $value[] = date('Y,m,d', strtotime( $selected['start_date'] ) );
    $value[] = $selected['total_earn_amount'];
  }
 $daily_final_earn = json_encode($value,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Result , I have for now

```
[
"2016,10,09",43.5968,
"2016,10,10",240.54155,
"2016,10,11",26.39,
"2016,10,12",49.34905,
"2016,10,13",226.46,
"2016,10,14",41.53405,
"2016,10,15",282.2825,
"2016,10,16",147.3975,
"2016,10,17",39.115,
"2016,10,18",104.35825
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while($selected = $statement->fetch()){
    $value[] = [
        //date('Y,m,d', strtotime( $selected['start_date'] ) ),
        'Date.UTC(' . date('Y,m,d', strtotime( $selected['start_date'] ) ) . ')',
        $selected['total_earn_amount'],
    ];
}

$daily_final_earn = json_encode($value,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

**Update** for getting equivalent of `Date.UTC()`:

```
while($selected = $statement->fetch()){
    $value[] = [
        // `strtotime` returns number of seconds since epoch starts
        // to get milliseconds - multiply it by 1000.
        // same result will be received when using `Date.UTC()`
        1000 * strtotime( $selected['start_date'] ),
        $selected['total_earn_amount'],
    ];
}

$daily_final_earn = json_encode($value,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: Thanks , that added [] but how do i get Date.UTC() and remove " from date .?

Comment: Needs to remove " , eveything else looks perfect..    ["Date.UTC(2016,10,09)",43.5968],["Date.UTC(2016,10,10)",240.54155]

Comment: This is `php`, you __can't__ do it.  What is `Date.UTC`? javascript function? Then think how to pass variables to this function on client side.

Comment: Or find the php-equivalent and convert your date. I suppose its `strtotime() * 1000`

Comment: Also, When I tried "[Date.UTC("+date('Y,m,d', strtotime( $selected['start_date'] ) ) +")", it returned [2016,240.54155],[2016,26.39]  only year , why is that ... wanted to learn if you have any explanations , would be appreciated

Comment: Because concatenation in php is done with `.`, this is __not__ javascript.

Comment: trying to build this CHART -- > [https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series]

Comment: Do you __understand__ that `Date.UTC` is a javascript function that returns some value. You can replace `Date.UTC(x,y,z)` with this value and everything will be the same.

Comment: that did the trick... thanks a lot , i was trying to create API link as this --> [https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json]

Comment: one issues , when I run Date.UTC(2016,10,9) , result is - 1478649600000 . FOR same date PHP return - 1475989200000 , I think doesn't display year.

Comment: Check your timezone. Though difference is too big.

Comment: I'm in EST but result should be same no .?  1000 * strtotime("2016-10-09")

Comment: `strtotime("2016-10-09")` is `1475964000`, `strtotime("2016-11-09");` is `1478646000`. Check your dates.

Comment: i'm checking it LIVE from php `1000 * strtotime( "2016-10-09" ) =  1475989200000` , from JS `Date.UTC(2016,10,09) = 1478649600000`

Comment: That's another strangeness of javascript. Number of moths are started from zero in it. So 10 is November. And if you've __read__ a manual for `Date.UTC`, for example here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC - you would have noticed that.

Comment: thanks for the info, can you check this link strange thing for both numbers .. check comments writter in DATA section  [http://jsfiddle.net/j2o5q24s/]

Comment: What strange thing?

Comment: php number doesn't display Year it returns time in report mousehover , while javascript number does... I got the point about month but still very confuse for year..

Comment: from `php 1000 * strtotime( "2016-10-09" ) ` there is no year `(Sunday. Oct 9. 05:00)` when hoverover || from javascript `Date.UTC(2016,10,09)` there is YEAR `(Wednesday. Nov 9. 2016)` when mousehover . How would i get year format with PHP .?

Comment: fix it by adding date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); in php , please add that to answer